# How to create parameterized queries in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Using parameterized queries with ms access 2003 integration.  To search any data according to different criteria.

Comment: I agree with ephilip, post this on SO and you'll get 5 answers in 2 minutes. ;)

Comment: hey guys thanks for the reply but can you tell what SO is?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) class, as well as the [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) class, with the proper connection string for [Access](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access#p20).

```
Dim sql as String = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN_A = @PARAM"
Dim connectionString as String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
   Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql)
   command.Connection = connection
   command.Params.Add("@PARAM", yourVariable)
   connection.Open()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(1)
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful: [Howto? Parameters and LIKE statement SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql)