# UPDATE statement failing when attempting to update access database - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to create a simple ticketing software for myself with a VB.Net front end and an `Access 2003` back end.  I have with allowing new rows to be added, but when I try to code the Update row `button`, it is giving me the error that says `Microsoft JET Database Engine - Syntax error in UPDATE statement.` I cannot find what the problem is.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ConnectString As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\aaron-pister\Desktop\New Role Notes\Issue Tracker Express\Issue Tracker Express\Issue Tracker.mdb")
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(ConnectString)
    con.Open()
    Dim Green42 As String = "UPDATE Issues Basic Details SET [Company Name] = '" & txtClientName.Text & "', [Status] = '" & cbStatus.Text & "', [Company Contact] = '" & txtClientContact.Text & "', [Description] = '" & txtDesc.Text & "', [Notes] = '" & txtRes.Text & "' WHERE [TicketNum] = '" & txtTicket.Text & "'"
    'con.Open()
    If txtClientName.Text <> "" Then
        Try
            'MyCom.CommandText = "UPDATE [Issues Basic Details] SET Company Name = '" & txtClientName.Text & "', Status = '" & cbStatus.Text & "', Company Contact = '" & txtClientContact.Text & "', Description = '" & txtDesc.Text & "', Notes = '" & txtRes.Text & "' WHERE TicketNum = '" & txtTicket.Text & "')"
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Green42.ToString, ConnectString)
            da.Fill(dt)
            da.Update(EsInfo1, "Issues Basic Details")
            MsgBox("Your record has been updated successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton1, "New Ticket Submitted")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Source & "-" & ex.Message)
            con.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("You must have an entry in the Client Name, Client Contact and Status fields. It is recommended to also have a value in the Description field.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Issue Tracker Express")
        btnNewIncident_Click(sender, e)
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table name has to be bracketed too:

```
Dim Green42 As String = "UPDATE [Issues Basic Details] SET [Company Name]..."
```

Also, [use parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) instead of putting the values into the string.  It avoids SQL Injection.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, as a general rule of thumb spaces, special characters and reserved keywords are all things to avoid when naming tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
UPDATE Issues Basic Details SET ...
```

Is not valid SQL. You need to help it by qualifying your table name:

```
UPDATE [Issues Basic Details] SET ...
```

A few other suggestions:

1. Use prepared statements (parameterize your SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks)
2. Don't define this type of behavior in a click event handler -- have a helper class to do this work so it can be re-used and isn't coupled directly to the UI.
3. Use `Using` statements. Your `OleDbConnection` class implements `IDisposable`. You aren't properly disposing this connection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by parameterize the SQL.  I think I understand your other two points, and understand them.  Can you provide examples of how I could parameterize my SQL in the code provided?

Comment: @AaronPister: See the Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2. It shows both the `Using` statement usage and the parameterization of a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

While it's hard to read your code at the moment, it does look like you are trying to do an "AdHoc" query, which can cause a lot of problems.

I'd recommend first changing your statement to a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851341/how-to-create-parameterized-queries-in-vb-net) to help diagnose issues too.