# How do i write a sql query with user input and wildcards

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, ado.net

Usually i write my where statements as `WHERE key=@0` then add a param. Now i would like the user to specific a few letters such as 'oat' and would like to stick wildcards around it `%oat%` which matches 'coating'. So how do i write the query so wildcards are around the user input (the 'seachword').

Now lets take it a step further. I would not like the user to write % so he cannot do blah%ing. Perhaps % is part of the sentence (or it could be flat out illegal but i prefer it be part of the sentence). How do i put my wildcards around a word or sentence and disallow the user from putting the wildcard between his words? (and preferably make % part of the sentence)

C# ado.net sql/sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: How do i put my wildcards around a word or sentence and disallow the user from putting the wildcard between his words? (and preferably make % part of the sentence)

I think you would need to Replace any `%` the user supplies with `\%` and use

```
LIKE @Expression ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements) (i.e. SQLiteCommand, a subclass of [DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx)), this will be taken care of for you.  E.g.:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (COLUMN LIKE = '%' + @input + '%')"))
{
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", input);
        // ...
}
```

See also this similar [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276).

Answer (score 1):

Continue using a param, but add the wildcard in the param prior to binding.

C#:

```
  param = '%' + Regex.Replace(param, @"[%?]", String.Empty) + '%'
```

SQL:

```
select * from ... where key like :param
```