# My Stored Procedure Not Working When i Use Like %% Instead Of "=" Sql Server ?? Query Attached

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i am trying to run sp its not giving any result when i replace "=" by "Like"

my query is define below,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectMentor] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Zip varchar(20)=NULL,
    @Company varchar(200)=NULL,
    @Designation varchar(100)=NULL,
    @Interest varchar(200)=NULL
    --@JobFunc varchar(200)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select ub.user_Id,ub.user_Fullname,up.Designation,up.Company from UserBasics UB 
inner join UserProfession up on  
ub.user_Id=up.Prof_ID 
where  (@Zip is null or ub.user_Zip = @Zip) and
    (@Interest is null or ub.user_Need = @Interest) and
--  (@JobFunc is null or m.mentor_jobFunction= @JobFunc) and
    (@Company is null or up.Company=@Company) and
    (@Designation is null or up.Designation=@Designation)
```

its working fine but when i replace "=" with "Like",

```
select ub.user_Id,ub.user_Fullname,up.Designation,up.Company from UserBasics UB 
inner join UserProfession up on  
ub.user_Id=up.Prof_ID 
where  (@Zip is null or ub.user_Zip like '%@Zip%') and
    (@Interest is null or ub.user_Need like '%@Interest%') and
--  (@JobFunc is null or m.mentor_jobFunction= @JobFunc) and
    (@Company is null or up.Company like '%@Company%') and
    (@Designation is null or up.Designation like '%@Designation%')
```

its not working ???

Hopes for your Suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Try '%' + @param + '%'. I bet it's just putting %@param% verbatim.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto? Parameters and LIKE statement SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select ub.user_Id,ub.user_Fullname,up.Designation,up.Company from UserBasics UB 
    inner join UserProfession up on  
    ub.user_Id=up.Prof_ID 
    where  (@Zip is null or ub.user_Zip like '%'+@Zip+'%') and
        (@Interest is null or ub.user_Need like '%'+@Interest+'%') and
    --  (@JobFunc is null or m.mentor_jobFunction= @JobFunc) and
        (@Company is null or up.Company like '%'+@Company+'%') and
        (@Designation is null or up.Designation like '%'+@Designation+'%')
```

Raj

Answer (score 4):

Your LIKE example is trying to match for those actual string values i.e.
user_Zip containing the literal text "@Zip"

You need to concatenate like this:

```
where  (@Zip is null or ub.user_Zip like '%' + @Zip + '%') and
... etc
```