# Using parameterized SQL LIKE Statements

Tags: c#, sql, sql-like, parameterized

I'm trying to parameterize my SQL Statements but I'm having some trouble with the LIKE statement. I tried different solutions but nothing works. My code:

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + form1.cusId.Text + "," + form1.cusName.Text" FROM " + form1.getTable() + " WHERE " + form1.getCusId() + " LIKE @filterCustomers", connection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filterCustomers", form1.filterCus().Trim() + "%");
```

I'm getting

> "Must declare the scalar variable @filterCustomers".

Why ist that happening? Since this is th common solution...

Comment: You seem to be injecting stuff into your SQL string all over the place, so I'm not sure you're reaping any of the primary benefits of parametrized queries.

Comment: What is the value of `form1.filterCus().Trim()` exactly? Debug your code and tell us. And since you want to get your table and column names dynamically, I hope you create a strong validation or black list for them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto? Parameters and LIKE statement SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql)

Comment: I've seen that in a couple of examples. It's just all about the apostophes isn't it? Nevermind... That example above doesn't work

Comment: btw ... this smells like [SQLInjection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)! And, ultimately, it looks like you are doing SQL in your web-layer - please look into n-tier-architecture (and ORM btw)

Comment: How to avoid injection? Should I replace every single parameter? So every columnname and the tablename?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@filterCustomers",SqlDbType.VarChar,8).Value = form1.filterCus().Trim() + "%";
```

Instead of:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filterCustomers", form1.filterCus().Trim() + "%");
```

You can change the`.VarChar` for what you data type is and the `8` for the required max field lenght, or remove the `,8` completely for no limit in the parameter lenght

Comment: What difference that makes? If OP's code won't work with his variables, your code don't work either in my opinion..

Comment: I get the same error message :( When I do this with not parameterized values then it's working fine

Comment: @ScorpX What `form1.filterCus().Trim()` returns exactly? And what are the names of your table and columns? And your column types?

Comment: Just thought since it said to declare the variable maybe the issue of that would be the way of declaration, I just posted this as a thing to try. nothing more. But @ScorpX perhaps its due to `form1.filterCus()`, have you tried replacing the value of the variable to something pre set? like set it instead of the `form1.filterCus()` to a string there.

Comment: form1.filterCus() is just a method that grabs the String from a textbox. The column type is an Integer but it worked that way everywhere. After the statement I use     "sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
                sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
                form1.setDataGrid = datTable;"

Comment: Perhaps the parameter doesn't work with the method, have you tried setting the output of the method to a variable before the query and using the varable to set the parameter value?

Comment: does the string get the value like it should? where does it break if you try it in those steps?

Comment: Yes the value is correct. It breaks when I fill the DataTable from the DataAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your string inside single quotes `'`:

```
...+" LIKE '"+ form1.filterCus().Trim()+"%'", connection);
```

if you don't worry about SQL INJECTION

**EDIT**: you can also use **dynamic sql**:

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC ('SELECT..... WHERE FIELD LIKE ''' + @filterCustomers + '%''')", connection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filterCustomers", form1.filterCus().Trim() + "%");
```

Comment: Think you made a small mistake with your awnser since `LIKE @filterCustomers", connection);` suddenly got something more added behind the value of the `LIKE` statment

Comment: When I try this he returns nothing when I'm searching an element.

Comment: @Scorp, because you are passing the parameter wrong

Comment: @Farhęg nope, that will render to `LIKE '@filterCustomers'` which will search for `@filterCustomers` and not its content. Please see this answer for [a correct solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/251380/57508).

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, of course it will, I just wanted to tell about right use of like statement

Comment: @Farhęg yep, absolutely. But, this still smells like [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Your edit doesn't make much sense: `@filterCustomers + '%'` and `form1.filterCus().Trim() + "%"` which will result in `foo%%`...