# Mysql WHERE LIKE with RadCombobox.Text

Tags: c#, mysql, where-clause, sql-like, radcombobox

I am having trouble with SELECT WHERE LIKE due to the use of @.

Using

```
string Mysql = "SELECT * FROM sytransactioncategory WHERE TransactionCategory LIKE '%' + @TransactionCategory + '%'";
```

Do not Work.

I found several interesting answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql) but I did not not manage to adapt it to my case.
Here is my current C# code:

```
string Mysql = "SELECT * FROM sytransactioncategory WHERE TransactionCategory LIKE @TransactionCategory";
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Mysql,ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionCategory", e.Text);
```

Anyone could give me a track please?

Comment: You're query construction in the first case is a little flawed, should be `....LIKE '%" + ....`. In the second case, you've not provided any `%` symbols, unless they are already in `e.Text`.

Comment: Nooooo, I've had a `your`/`you're` typo immortalized! ;_;

Comment: @Uueerdo you can edit your own comments.

Comment: @OllieJones AFAIK, not after a certain amount of time passes.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's right.

Comment: Uueerdo, the second case is what is working so far. It is my working basis. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: And for the first case, @ is missing. you should read WHERE TransactionCategory LIKE '%' + @TransactionCategory + '%'

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator in MySQL works on numbers.

You want `... LIKE CONCAT('%', TransactionCategory, '%')` if you're trying to construct strings in your query.

The kicker is this:   `0 + 'somethingrandom'` has the result value of zero, because MySQL tries to convert `'somethingrandom'` to an integer, and decides it's zero.

```
0 + '2randomthings'
```

has a value of 2.

So, your query is saying `WHERE column LIKE 0` which

1. doesn't fail by throwing any kind of syntax error.
2. doesn't find anything useful.

Debugging this kind of stuff in MySQL is a pain in the synt*x

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ollie. 
I tried your solution in phpmyadmin and it looks like these both options work:

- LIKE CONCAT('%', 'TransactionCategory', '%') (meaning your answer adding the ' before and after TransactionCategory)
- LIKE '%TransactionCategory%'

So my problem is now: how can I replace TransactionCategory by @TransactionCategory, which is the value of what is entered in the RadComboBox "rcbTransactionCategory"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make the second method work, it's better than the first.

To solve your problem, in c#, your statement should be like this:

string Mysql = "SELECT * FROM sytransactioncategory WHERE TransactionCategory LIKE '%" + str_TransactionCategory + "%'";

Where str_TransactionCategory is the variable holding your search value.

Comment: Hello Tim. I am a bit confused as first you advise me to use the second method ('%TransactionCategory%') and then you give me a third one ('%" + str_TransactionCategory + "%') that I cannot run successfully in phpmyadmin. (it doesn't return any value). I tried the following to use your str_TransactionCategory: RadComboBox rcbAccountCode = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rcbAccountCode"); and then how can I state str_TransactionCategory = rcbAccountCode.Text?

Comment: You need gather the value from your form somehow,maybe just like your code. I don't have your whole setup and it's up to you to find out, maybe by reading a complete tutorial somewhere. The second method makes things complicated and you can master it later.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the answer was quite simple. No need to use findcontrol. This works for me:

```
string Mysql = "SELECT * FROM sytransactioncategory WHERE TransactionCategory LIKE CONCAT('%', @TransactionCategory, '%');
```

Thank you for your help.