# C# MySQL Transaction commit

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I want to update ~50 rows. So i do it in a foreach
The Code run without any errors but there are no changes in the database.

```
public void updateItems(List<product> prdList)
    {
        MySqlTransaction tr = null;

        try
        {
            tr = this.con.BeginTransaction();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Transaction = tr;

            foreach (product prd in prdList)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE products SET title='@title', quantity='@quantity' WHERE itemId LIKE '@itemId'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", prd.title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", prd.quantity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemId", prd.itemId);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            try
            {
                tr.Rollback();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
            }

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

If i print the Query String and run it on SQL-Bash, it works fine.

Comment: you're quoting your parameters. that is wrong. parameter go in "naked", never quoted. `set title=@title`, not `set title='@title'`.

Comment: And don't use `AddWithValue`, be specific about the types you are adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use single quotes with your parameters. With single quotes, your query see them as a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), not a parameter.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE products SET title=@title, quantity=@quantity WHERE itemId LIKE @itemId";
```

Also since you try to parameterize `LIKE` part, you need to use [`%..%` part in your parameter part or like '%' + @itemId + '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql).

By the way, if you have more than one `prd` in your `prdList`, you need to clear your all parameters at the top of your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (product prd in prdList)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    ...
    ...
}
```

As a last point, don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size. And don't forget to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically.

Comment: Example 

DB:
itemID - 0001
itemID - 00001

Now if i search %itemId i get 2 results back or?

Comment: *If i use Parameters.Add() VS display .....Add() ist veraltet: Use AddWithValue()

Answer (score 0):

change your command statement like this

from

```
"UPDATE products SET title='@title', quantity='@quantity' WHERE itemId LIKE '@itemId'";
```

to

```
"UPDATE products SET title=@title, quantity=@quantity WHERE itemId LIKE @itemId";
```

and dont forget to add

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

you should clear the parameter every loop.