# Vb.net query for a string that contains another string

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a table adapter called Tabone and i want to create a query a column where
i can retrieve values that are like or contains some character or prefix from the query string .

for example :
if i write in a textbox 20 it retrieves all records which contains 20 whether in the beginning or middle or end and each time i add more character it filters more records.

i thought of using textbox_textchanged event

```
my sql query was :
select [ID] [Name] [description] from [Tabone] where [Name] like ?
```

but it does not do the job

Comment: And I suggest that you fetch all the data to a data table.Then under the text changed event, you can do the filter from the data table.

Comment: Let me straighten out a bit of the semantics. The table in your database is called Tabone; your TableAdapter name is TaboneTableAdapter. I am not familiar with TableAdapters but you can pull a DataTable out of one with the `.GetData` method. Then you can use the `.Select(string)` method on the resulting DataTable to get the rows your are interested in. No need to hit the database again.

Comment: @Mary i'm displaying the result in a datagridview with a bindingsource.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/251276/5045688

Comment: Try this `like '%" & textbox1.Text & "%'"`